# Audio processing with fft iphone app

Tags: iphone, audio, fft, fftw, spectrum

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [AurioTouch & FFT for an instrument tuner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447059/auriotouch-fft-for-an-instrument-tuner)

I am working on one app in which i need to do the spectrum analysis of the incoming audio sounds.
I am new to it only thing i know is that i need to use the FFT. I looked in to the aurio touch app but couldn't understood it. if any one have sample code or simple way so that i can do it please let me know.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are **lots** of questions and answers on SO already about this subject - try searching for "aurio", "FFT", "Hanning", "power spectrum", etc

Comment: Many duplicates, e.g. [AurioTouch & FFT for an instrument tuner](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447059/auriotouch-fft-for-an-instrument-tuner) and  [calculating frequency with apple's auriotouch example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856654/calculating-frequency-with-apples-auriotouch-example) and [Determining what frequencies correspond to the x axis in aurioTouch sample application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2949893/determining-what-frequencies-correspond-to-the-x-axis-in-auriotouch-sample-applic)...

Comment: ...and [Do you know a good and efficient FFT?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592345/do-you-know-a-good-and-efficient-fft)